# How to package a shell script?

Tags: command-line, application-development, packaging, development

I have a shell script . I want to convert the script into a terminal application which can be installed using `sudo apt-get install` and can be run through the terminal by typing the name of the application.

I am new to development in Ubuntu and I am not able to understand how to proceed.

Comment: You should look here - http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/

Comment: The main source code is also a script file...Is the packaging for scripts done in the same way as any programming languages like c, c++ etc source code?...